# How do I assign this regex match from an OUTPUT value to a variable using bash?

Tags: regex, bash

My current value of `$OUTPUT` is:

`Updating (122 files)`

In this case, I want to capture the `122` and assign it to a variable.

I was thinking of using a regex like `\d*` to capture the number, but I'm unclear on the syntax for working with regular expressions in bash.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use sed:

```
OUTPUT=$(echo $OUTPUT| sed 's/[^0-9]//g')
```

to delete all non-digit characters for instance.

Answer (score 2):

Just use [parameter expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02):

```
$ output='Updating (122 files)'
$ output="${output##*(}"
$ output="${output%% *}"
$ echo "$output"
122
```

You can tweak the pattern if you need more flexible matching.

Answer (score 2):

Using regular expressions,

```
$ regex="Updating \(([[:digit:]]+) files\)"
$ [[ $OUTPUT =~ $regex ]]
$ echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
122
```

In this case, there is enough context that you could simplify the regular expression to

```
regex="Updating \((.*) files\)"
```